# How this website is loading the background image

Tags: css

I tried searching in the firebug but i wasnt able to find how this website is loading the background image

http://hiddendepth.ie/

Is it a new technique or something ?

Comment: the background image is not showing up in html or css !!!

Comment: sorry i got it, please ignore

Answer (score 3):

It is no new technique, it is inside the following class, found with Firebug:

```
.home .hd_hero {
    background: url('../img/home/responsive-digital-web-agency-dublin-2.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover #1A1A1A;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Dont know what new thing op was looking at?